# GRUNT - Install Grunt Packages?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, less

Can anyone advise what I'm doing wrong here (i'm new to grunt) a colleage has supplied me with a base gruntfile setup

[image]

I have installed node,js, and grunt but I cant figure out how to install the various packages (uglify, concat etc) - which command should I use for this?

Comment: To learn more about npm: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-npm-to-manage-node-js-packages-on-a-linux-server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first question you must ask yourself is, "what are the names of the grunt dependencies?"

**The quick answer:**

Simply execute the `npm install <package-name>` for each package you wish to install.  *For the most part*, I consider the package-names to be equivalent to their github name.  ( `grunt-contrib-concat` for example. )

`npm install grunt-contrib-concat` will install it, then go on to the next.

**Improving Maintainability:**

For optimal maintainability and cross developer/environment support you should consider using `package.json` to list your dependencies.

Once you have all of your dependencies listed in `package.json`, you can then run `npm install` and all of them will be installed should the need ever arise.  (For development based dependency vs runtime/production based dependency management, read on!)

**Best Practices:**

The optimal workflow with node js is to use `npm init` first, so that your package.json file is created for you.  then once you have a package.json, you can install each of your dependencies/devDependencies by either adding them to their respective lists in the json file or adding them to their respective lists *on the fly* by using `npm install <package name> --save` or `--save dev` respectivly.

> NOTE: IF you are experimenting, and you'd rather NOT save a node module to your dependency list, then a simple `npm install <package name>` will do.

At this point, I do recommend searching for `npm package.json best practices` - as you will find some valuable information regarding your workflow for nodejs.  Dependency management can be amazing, but only if you know how to really take advantage of the utilities provided.

Consider the following excerpt from a package.json file:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "backbone": "*",
    "underscore": "~*",
    "requirejs": "*"
    "jquery": "*"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "*",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "*",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "*",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "*"
  },
```

The example we see is that the npm packages under dependencies will install when running `npm install --production`, the development packages will be installed automatically when running `npm install --development`,

> NOTE: You can change your node environment as well which modifies the usage of a simple `npm install` with no flags.

For the most part, grunt is used for development, so I believe it would be more common to find anything related to grunt being in `devDependencies`

**A sample package.json:**

http://browsenpm.org/package.json

Answer (score 1):

if you have package.json with devDependencies (or dependencies) defined, all you need to run is `npm install` then `grunt`

Otherwise run something like this to install and save them to your package.json

`npm install --save-dev <package-name>`

Comment: Just note that if the `Gruntfile.js` does not contain a `default` task then you will need to specify which task you want to run when executing the `grunt` command. If the file doesn't contain a `default` task, IMHO it's probably best to add one.